# Can I use cosine distance as inputs for model in text classification task?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, data-science

I mostly deal with text data. I'm not sure if I can do something like this.

```
for plaint,law in zip(train_seqs1,train_seqs2):
   plaint_emb = get_tokens_embeddings(plaint).numpy().flatten()
   law_emb = get_tokens_embeddings(law).numpy().flatten()
   cosine_dis = cosine(plaint_emb,law_emb)
```

I tried getting word embeddings from bert , and used them to calculate distance between two texts. I want to know that , can I use this cosine distances to train model? If I can , how to preprocess these number inputs. I want to know the right threshold of cosine distances to predict that these two texts are relevant or not relevant to each other. (Binary classification)

Comment: I'm confused. Is your goal to train a model to predict whether two embeddings are very different in terms of the cosine similarity between their Bert embeddings? What's the point? Why not just *use* the cosine similarity between their Bert embeddings? Is this a practice in distillation of some sort? As for the threshold, you'll likely have to tune it on some held out dataset, e.g. to achieve some desired TPR or FPR.

Comment: My goal is to train a model to predict if two texts are relevant to each other , in this case , plaint and law content, based on cosine similarity. Could you give me some advices how to tune it using cosine distance as inputs?

Comment: My advice is to not train one model to approximate another model. Doing so will never yield a better model. Your current strategy is to use bert embeddings to generate ground truth data to train another model. If the bert embeddings already provide a *good* space for measuring similarity, then there's no reason to train a *new* model on top of them. If they *don't* provide a good space for measuring similarity, then using them as ground truth for training a new model will just give you a bad model. That's why "ground truth" is called "ground truth". It's supposed to be true, not approximated.

Comment: Would not recommend training model to approximate another as @AlexanderGuyer mentioned. You might want to try using [SPC models](https://simpletransformers.ai/docs/sentence-pair-classification/) after tagging your texts in the specified format.